# How to modify posted form data within controller action before sending to view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to render the same view after a successful action (rather than use RedirectToAction), but I need to modify the model data that is rendered to that view. The following is a contrived example that demonstrates two methods that that do not work:

```
    [AcceptVerbs("POST")]
    public ActionResult EditProduct(int id, [Bind(Include="UnitPrice, ProductName")]Product product) {
        NORTHWNDEntities entities = new NORTHWNDEntities();

        if (ModelState.IsValid) {
            var dbProduct = entities.ProductSet.First(p => p.ProductID == id);
            dbProduct.ProductName = product.ProductName;
            dbProduct.UnitPrice = product.UnitPrice;
            entities.SaveChanges();
        }

        /* Neither of these work */
        product.ProductName = "This has no effect";
        ViewData["ProductName"] = "This has no effect either";

        return View(product);
    }
```

Does anyone know what the correct method is for accomplishing this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

After researching this further, I have an explanation why the following code has no effect in the Action:

```
product.ProductName = "This has no effect";
ViewData["ProductName"] = "This has no effect either";
```

My View uses HTML Helpers:

```
<% Html.EditorFor(x => x.ProductName);
```

HTML Helpers uses the following order precedence when attempting lookup of the key:

1. ViewData.ModelState dictionary entry
2. Model property (if a strongly typed view. This property is a shortcut to View.ViewData.Model)
3. ViewData dictionary entry

For HTTP Post Actions, ModelState is always populated, so modifying the Model (product.ProductName) or ViewData directly (ViewData["ProductName"]) has no effect.

If you do need to modify ModelState directly, the syntax to do so is:

```
ModelState.SetModelValue("ProductName", new ValueProviderResult("Your new value", "", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Or, to clear the ModelState value:

```
ModelState.SetModelValue("ProductName", null);
```

You can create an extension method to simplify the syntax:

```
public static class ModelStateDictionaryExtensions {
    public static void SetModelValue(this ModelStateDictionary modelState, string key, object rawValue) {
        modelState.SetModelValue(key, new ValueProviderResult(rawValue, String.Empty, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    }
}
```

Then you can simply write:

```
ModelState.SetModelValue("ProductName", "Your new value");
```

For more details, see [Consumption of Data in MVC2 Views](http://www.gxclarke.org/2010/05/consumption-of-data-in-mvc2-views.html).

Comment: Thank you, this was very useful. I used this to remove a credit card number from being redisplayed after an incorrect one is entered. I was surprised at how non-trivial/non-intuitive this task was.

Answer (score 2):

The values are stored in `ModelState`.

This should do what you want:

```
ModelState.SetModelValue("ProductName", "The new value");
```

I wouldn't suggest doing that though... the correct method would be to follow the [PRG (Post/Redirect/Get) pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

HTHs,
Charles

EDIT: Updated to reflect the better was of setting the `ModelState` value as found by @Gary

Comment: Thanks--that solution does indeed work, although I needed to specify "product.ProductName" for the key rather than just "ProductName".

In my real scenario (the sample code was made up for illustration), I needed to clear a particular value after a validation failure, so I didn't want to redirect. When validations are successful, I am following the PRG pattern that you recommended. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

This will trigger the model to re-evaluate under simple conditions:

```
ModelState.Clear();
model.Property = "new value";
TryValidateModel(model);
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Perform ModelState.Clear() before you change the model.

```
...
ModelState.Clear()
dbProduct.ProductName = product.ProductName;
dbProduct.UnitPrice = product.UnitPrice;
...
```

Comment: As its name indicates, ModelState.Clear() deletes the entire model state, which is undesirable.