# ASP.NET Core - Changing form values after a post

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm probably missing something very obvious, but all I'm trying to do is have a simple form, allow it to POST, change one of the fields, and when it returns it should show me the changed value. Simple, right?

The model looks like this:

```
public class TestModel
{
    public string Field1 { get; set; }
    public string Field2 { get; set; }
}
```

The controller actions:

```
public IActionResult Test()
{
    return View(new TestModel());
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Test(TestModel model)
{
    model.Field1 = "changed"; // this seems to be ignored
    return View(model);
}
```

The view:

```
@model AspNetCoreTest1.Models.TestModel
<form method="post" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Test">
    <input asp-for="Field1" />
    <br />
    <input asp-for="Field2" />
    <br />
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

I can see the form and it POSTs back (I can see the values I typed in the model), but after the POST the form still shows the values I typed. It does NOT show `changed` for the first field.

(I'm using ASP.NET Core 1.1)

Thoughts?

Comment: Try removing `return View(new TestModel());` from `HttpGet`.. Just keep `return View()`.

Comment: Just tried; same thing

Comment: Can you place a debugger in the view to see if you are getting updated model values?

Comment: Ha! I didn't know you can put a breakpoint in HTML, nice :) Yes, I just did that and Field1 is showing up as "changed". So weird...

Comment: Note: while Field1 == "changed" the value that gets sent to the browser still shows the value that I typed in the form.

Comment: Then the view model binding is not properly done is what I feel...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to modify posted form data within controller action before sending to view?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686652/how-to-modify-posted-form-data-within-controller-action-before-sending-to-view)

Comment: @CodeCaster thanks, that makes sense

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can't directly make changes to the model which is passed and hope for that it will reflect in UI. The solution for your problem is as follows.

Replace this line of code `model.Field1 = "changed";` with following if you are using C# 6.0:

```cs
ModelState.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == nameof(model.Field1)).Value.RawValue = "changed";
```

For earlier C# versions:

```cs
ModelState.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "Field1")).Value.RawValue = "changed";
```

Comment: OK... your code works, but, not intuitive to say the least (comment on the framework, not your answer). The official documentation passes the model back to the View (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/controller-methods-views) on POST. I just tried simply passing View() without the model and that also works; which makes sense given what you're saying. What's the benefit of it working this way?

Comment: After reading @CodeCaster 's link it now makes sense what it's going on behind the scenes. I still think it's a poor design decision. Thanks to both of you for your help

Answer (score 6):

you can just call :

```
ModelState.Clear();
return View(YourModel);
```

this will clear all ModelState values

Answer (score 1):

Note: This is only a problem if you are using ASP.NET input controls. For example, if your HTML contains

```
<p>@model.Field1</p>
```

Then you can update Field1 in the controller

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Test(TestModel model)
{
   model.Field1 = "changed"; // this will update as expected
   return View(model);
}
```

You only need to use the solution given by Vadent when your HTML contains

```
<input asp-for="Field1" class="form-control" />
```